# How to delete elements from list of tuples?

Tags: python, list

I want to delete the list of tuple in python. I have the list

`l = [('name','sam'),('age', 20),('sex', 'male')]`

and another list of tuples

`r = [('name','sam'),('age', 20)]`

I am trying to delete those elements which are in `r` and `l` both. I am doing this:

```
for item in l:
   if item in r:
       del item
```

But the elements are not deleting. The output is nothing and when I print the modified list:

`>>> l`

Then original list is printing.

`[('name','sam'),('age', 20),('sex', 'male')]`

Please help me, how can I delete elements from list of tuples.

Comment: The cause of the observed behavior is, that with `for item in l` you create a (temporary) reference to each list-item and `del`ing that reference does not touch the list itself. Also it is always a bad idea to try to modify a list you are looping over with a `for`-loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tranform both lists in sets and subtract them:

```
l = [('name','sam'),('age', 20),('sex', 'male')]
r = [('name','sam'),('age', 20)]
```

The following line will return only the elements that are in `l` but aren't in `r`:

```
set(l) - set(r)
```

Comment: Good answer, but I think it does not exactly do what he has described. In particular, when the items in `l` aren't unique, then your code also removes the duplicates. Which might or might not be what he actually wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `filter()`.

```
for item in filter(lambda x: x not in r, l):
    # You can use your items here

# The list gets out of scope, so if there are no other references,
# the garbage collector will destroy it anyway
```

Or, if you need to use the list elsewhere too, you might also consider creating a new list instead, using a list comprehension:

```
l = [i for i in l if i not in r]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return a list of items that are in l and not in r.

The difference between this solution and the solution to substract sets is that you do not lose information if you have duplicates inside your list. You lose this information with substracting sets

```
difference = [item for item in l if item not in r]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to go screw this problem:

1. find AND of those list by `l and r` for finding which are common in both then  use to manipulate this in such a way: `[x for x in l if x not in l and r ]`. this will be little more efficient than above answers.
2. Correct marked answer will fall in some cases like what if `len(l) < len(r)`. so for overcome this problem simply 
   `list=[]
   p = l and r
   list.extend([ [x for x in l if x not in p ], [x for x in r if x not in p ]])`

   Hope it will fade out some uncovers.